# Как загрузить фото в кеш до запуска слайдера?

Tags: javascript, кэширование

Господа, есть такой простой слайдер.  Как видно из примера фото не отображаются сразу. Как до запуска слайдера загрузить фотографии в кеш и брать их уже от туда?

Маленькое дополнение. Это могут быть не только фото... Например: видео, музыкальные файлы...  И естественно не в слайдере, а где то еще... Меня интересует сама логика...  Ну и маленький пример с кодом, чтобы было понятнее. 
Я хочу подобные файлы загружать  заранее.

---

P.S.  Тут мне уже ответили, но у меня на компьютере все ровно тормозит.  И не понятно, что как и для чего...

```js
var sliderFoto = [
  'url(https://get.wallhere.com/photo/trees-forest-fall-waterfall-water-nature-rocks-national-park-pond-jungle-stream-rainforest-watercourse-wasserfall-habitat-natural-environment-body-of-water-water-feature-57484.jpg)',
  'url(http://ru.artsdot.com/ADC/Photos-ImgScreen.nsf/O/P-AC6V56/$FILE/Buildings-night_city_65_.Jpg)',
  'url(https://cdn.wallaps.com/wallpapers/10000/2870.jpg)',
  'url(http://on-desktop.com/wps/Nature_Beach_Bright_paints_of_coast_023115_.jpg)',
  'url(http://wallpaperscraft.ru/image/ravnina_zelen_solnce_gory_derevya_trava_326_2560x1600.jpg)'
];

var sliderBox = document.getElementById('sliderBox');

sliderBox.style.backgroundImage = sliderFoto[4];
//sliderBox.style.backgroundSize = 'cover';

var count = 0;
(function() {
  setInterval(function() {
    if (count >= sliderFoto.length) {
      count = 0;
    }

    sliderBox.style.backgroundImage = sliderFoto[count++];
  }, 5000)
}())
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #272727;
  color: white;
}

#wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#sliderBox {
  position: relative;
  top: 20px;
  left: calc(50% - 175px);
  width: 350px;
  height: 230px;
  background-size: cover;
  transition: all .5s;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="sliderBox">

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: скорее всего, "копать" Вам надо в эту сторону. https://habrahabr.ru/post/279291/. Я попробовал, но "грунт" что-то твердоват)

Comment: а почему именно бэкграунд? почему не картинкой обычной? Если бэкгранудом, то возможно просто в сами стили прописать классы, с этими картинками? и просто делать ротацию добавляя определенные классы?

Comment: @NeedHate, это для простоты примера... меня же не способ замены интересует...

Comment: Т.е. вопрос именно в: возможно ли предзагрузить что-то до момента его рендеринга?

Comment: да да да.........

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Создаем элемент - image - new Image() или через document.createElement('img');
2. Проверяем через промисы "подгрузилась" ли картинка;
3. Запускаем наш скрипт, который использует эти картинки, но, уже из кэша.

Через Network видно, что картинки подгружаются, а потом используются из кэша без подзагрузок.

```js
console.clear();
var links = [
  'http://via.placeholder.com/350x230/33ff99/555555?text=Slide_1',
  'http://via.placeholder.com/350x230/33ff99/555555?text=Slide_2',
  'http://via.placeholder.com/350x230/33ff99/555555?text=Slide_3',
];

const sliderFunc = () => {
  const sliderBox = document.getElementById('sliderBox');
  const img = sliderBox.querySelector('img');

  img.src = `${links[0]}`;

  var count = 0;
  (function() {
    setInterval(function() {
      if (count == links.length) {
        count = 0;
      }
      img.src = `${links[count++]}`;
    }, 1000)
  }())

}

const checkImage = path =>
  new Promise(resolve => {
    const img = new Image();
    img.onload = () => resolve({
      path,
      status: 'ok'
    });
    img.src = path;
  }).then(result => console.log(result.status, '...image is loaded from', path));

const loadImg = (paths) => Promise.all(paths.map(checkImage)).then(results => console.log('...all images are loaded')).then(sliderFunc);

loadImg(links)
```

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #272727;
  color: white;
}

#wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#sliderBox {
  width: 150px;
  height: 90px;
  background-size: cover;
  transition: all .5s;
}

img {
  width: 350px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="sliderBox">
    <img src="" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

**UPD**

Добавил консоль логи, где сообщается о подгрузке нового изображения, после загрузки всех изображений выводится соответствующее сообщение. 
Единственную проблему, которую я обнаружил с предзагрузкой вот этот вот адрес:
https://get.wallhere.com/... 
Каждый раз get как будто заново перезагружает одно и тоже изображение. С остальными такого нет, думаю здесь именно в этом ресурсе кроется нюанс.
А так, network показывает вполне ожидаемый результат: *(from disk cache)*

Comment: NeedHate, скопировал к себе на комп твой ответ и если честно то фотки так же грузятся не равномерно...  можешь описать свой пример, комментами, что  как там происходит...?

Comment: Дополнил ответ.

Comment: NeedHate, Благодарю, разобрался...