# Загружать картинки заранее, чтобы не было видно процесса загрузки?

Tags: javascript, css, css3, reactjs

Есть n-ое количество картинок. При нажатии на кнопку, одна картинка сменяет другую. Но есть время,когда она загружается. некая пауза. 
Можно ли сразу грузить картинки каким-то образом, чтобы юзер не видел процесс загрузки картинки?

Comment: Вы хотите, чтобы картинка погрузилась полностью, а не так чтобы загрузилась 1/3 и ниже белое, потом подгружаются остальные части?

Comment: Можно, например, загружаемую картинку делать невидимой до тех пор пока она не загрузится

Comment: да. при нажатии на кнопку видели картинку полностью, а не ее загрузку(1/3, 1/2 и т.д.).

Comment: нажимаем на кнопку, сразу показывается картинка целиком

Comment: сейчас же. нажимаем на кнопку, видим вместо картинки несоклкьо секунд пустое место и рамку вокруг нее

Comment: @werty загуглите "Learn How: Asynchronous Image Loading with JavaScript"  и перейдите в блог teamtreehouse, там расписывается, как сделать так, чтобы картинка показывалась только после полной загрузки, а до загрузки будет отображаться иконка загрузки.

Comment: а если . у меня картинка вставляется бэкграундом в div? background-image

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как загрузить фото в кеш до запуска сладера?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/759826/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b3%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b7%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%84%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%b5%d1%88-%d0%b4%d0%be-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0)

Answer (score 1):

Вы добавляете картинки в слайдер по одной? Добавьте их сразу все в слайдер, а неактивные как-нибудь скройте, например с помощь overflow: hidden. Но не ставьте им display: none, тогда они не будут подгружаться заранее. Вот пример как можно добавить прелоадер к картинке:

```js
  var img = document.querySelector('img');
  img.addEventListener('load', ()=> img.classList.add('show'));
```

```css
.image
{
  position: relative;
}

.image:before
{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: 1;
  content: 'LOADER'
}

.image > img
{
  opacity: 0;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  transition: opacity 0.5s;
}

.image > img.show
{ 
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="image">
  <img src="https://files.adme.ru/files/news/part_160/1608965/5601015---1509353172-650-65b6383f12-1509696697.jpg" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

- Самый современный способ: высокоприоритетная предзагрузка через `rel="preload"` – `<link rel="preload" href="/test-img.jpg" as="image">`. К сожалению, [работает не везде](https://caniuse.com/#search=preload). Для неподдерживаемых браузеров можно использовать другой метод, но уже низкоприоритетной загрузки – `<link rel="prefetch" href="/test-img.jpg">`.
- В url закодировать картинку в `base64`, вместо пути на файл – но размер файла вырастет где-то в 1.5 раза;
- Использовать на всём сайте единый спрайт – изображение менять нужно будет через `background-position`;
- Грузить картинку где-то на сайте, но скрывать её через `visibility: hidden` – если скрывать через `display: none`, то элемент выпадет из потока и не загрузится.