# Каким образом делаются переходы?

Tags: javascript, slider

Как реализуются такие переходы, как на скриншоте?

Если взять и cделать слайдер в ручную, не плагином и не готовым слайдером!
Там переход кубиками, есть разнообразные переходы между слайдами... каким образом реализуются переходы?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Оригинал вопроса : https://toster.ru/q/503408

Вопрос заинтересовал и меня так же...

Comment: На самом деле на тостере же есть ответ. Картинка разбивается на несколько div с одним и тем-же изображением, просто бэкграунд в каждом, имеет свое смещение. По таймеру это обновляется, в разном порядке, откуда и появляется такой визуальный эффект.

Comment: пример наглядный у меня в вопросе

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/759826/Как-загрузить-фото-в-кеш-до-запуска-сладера

Comment: @Air  да вроде в вопросе нету подобного ... либо я не заметил ...

Comment: @Sublihim  ответ я не видел ... уже прочитал

Comment: @МаксимЛенский, если честно не понял чем ты?

Comment: Это пропаганда Ксении Собчаг  расходимся!!

Comment: По мне так больше похоже на предвыборную агитацию Ксюши, чем вопрос о программировании))))))

Comment: @Air вот вот!! :))

Comment: @Air я только не понял технически как реализуются эти переходы , разбить изображение на фрагменты я знаю как , но как спозиционировать картинку на все фрагменты я не знаю ..

Comment: @МаксимЛенский, можно по разному, допустим можно реализовать так... возьми каждое действие отдельной функцией...   и запускай тот или иной цикл тогда когда тебе надо... Вопрос очень общий....

Comment: @Air  на этот общий вопрос нету ответа в интернете ... ни одного примера реализации .. только ссылки на wowslider и другие

Comment: Ты лучше переформулируй вопрос, и укажи что именно у тебя не получается и что именно тебя смущает...

Comment: @Air  написано же Там переход кубиками - вот именно как это реализовать ...?

Answer (score 2):

Есть много способов, один из них: `canvas`:

Пишешь в `canvas` картинку, разбиваешь на блоки и управляешь ими как хочешь, НО без фреймворка для работы с ним - тяжеловато будет, да и уже готовых решений таких эффектов для изображений в `canvas` есть куча... достаточно лишь подключить...

Еще один способ (но как на меня, более "дикий") - `div`-ы (или любые другие блоки) с background-image и background-position (+ css анимация)... да и куча всего остального (это уже смотря какая фантазия)