# Как кэшировать изображения

Tags: javascript

У меня есть галерея, но картинки не прогружается все, как мне загрузить например из массива все картинки, а потом уже запускать сайт, вот как я вижу:
Юзер запускает сайт, идёт прелоадер, в это время подгружаются в кэш все картинки, и тогда уже запусксется сайт.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как загрузить фото в кеш до запуска сладера?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/759826/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b3%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b7%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%84%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%b5%d1%88-%d0%b4%d0%be-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0)

Comment: @Air, тут вопрос в том, как именно задаются картинки, если они жестко прописаны в разметке - то не дубликат

Comment: @Grundy,ок.....

Answer (score 0):

Вынесите пути в массив, и используйте следующую конструкцию. В цикле загружается создается новый объект image через конструктор [Image()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/Image).

```js
let array = ['https://cs6.pikabu.ru/post_img/big/2015/06/18/3/1434596941_632146314.jpg', 'http://s.mediasole.ru/images/75/75506/d89e2a91d9932fef64ac532f756cbd06.jpg', 'http://www.bugaga.ru/uploads/posts/2017-03/1489052003_kotik-hosiko-1.jpg'];

let imageCount = 0;

for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  let img = new Image();
  img.onload = function() {
    imageCount++;
    console.log('загрузилось изображение');
    if (imageCount == array.length) {
      document.getElementById('preloader').style.display = 'none';
    }
  }
  img.src = array[i];
}
```

```html
<div id="preloader">Прелоадер</div>
```

Comment: и как это поможет дождаться?

Comment: Как вариант поставить флаг isLoad=true, если цикл завершиться флаг перевести в false и скрыть прелоадер, то после этого продолжить загрузку остального контента, а изображения будут уже в кэше браузера и будут доставаться уже оттуда.

Comment: `onload` - это обработчик события - цикл завершится заведомо раньше того, как сработает хотя бы первый обработчик.

Comment: Попробуй привести пример кода, о чем ты говоришь.

Answer (score 0):

Можно воспользоваться событием [`window.onload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload) оно срабатывает когда уже загружены все стили, скрипты, картинки, фреймы.

Картинки при этом должны быть прописаны непосредственно в Html, а не подгружаться асинхронно.

Например так:

```
window.onload = function(){
    // hide preloader
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- Самый современный способ: высокоприоритетная предзагрузка через `rel="preload"` – `<link rel="preload" href="/test-img.jpg" as="image">`. К сожалению, [работает не везде](https://caniuse.com/#search=preload). Для неподдерживаемых браузеров можно использовать другой метод, но уже низкоприоритетной загрузки – `<link rel="prefetch" href="/test-img.jpg">`.
- В url закодировать картинку в `base64`, вместо пути на файл – но размер файла вырастет где-то в 1.5 раза;
- Использовать на всём сайте единый спрайт – изображение менять нужно будет через `background-position`;
- Грузить картинку где-то на сайте, но скрывать её через `visibility: hidden` – если скрывать через `display: none`, то элемент выпадет из потока и не загрузится.