# Как кэшировать изображение и плавно изменять фон?

Tags: javascript, css, изображения, кэширование

У блока есть `background-image: url("../img/header__bg_3.jpg")`. Нужно заранее подгрузить изображение, что бы менять его `url` через `js` без мигания. Подскажите, как лучше реализовать это, или лучше будет сделать другим способом?

Еще возникла мыслить, что после того, как их кэшировать, необходимо сделать проверку на наличие этих изображений в кэше, что бы каждый раз их не подгружать.

**P.S:** Если будет необходимо, я сделаю пример.

**P.S.S:** По мимо кэширование, мне необходимо плавно менять фон у элемента.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как загрузить фото в кеш до запуска сладера?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/759826/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b3%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b7%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%84%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%b5%d1%88-%d0%b4%d0%be-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0)

Comment: @Air частично он отвечает на мой вопрос, но мне необходимо еще плавно менять фон у элемента. идеи есть, но без кэширования я его не пробовал реализовывать. спасибо

Comment: Виталик Черный, Плавность, это у же `css` добавь элементу `transition`

Comment: @Air я так и сделал. просто думал, может есть идеи по лучше)

Comment: Поверь, это лучший вариант))))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Самый современный способ: высокоприоритетная предзагрузка через `rel="preload"` – `<link rel="preload" href="/test-img.jpg" as="image">`. К сожалению, [работает не везде](https://caniuse.com/#search=preload). Для неподдерживаемых браузеров можно использовать другой метод, но уже низкоприоритетной загрузки – `<link rel="prefetch" href="/test-img.jpg">`.
- В url закодировать картинку в `base64`, вместо пути на файл – но размер файла вырастет где-то в 1.5 раза;
- Использовать на всём сайте единый спрайт – изображение менять нужно будет через `background-position`;
- Грузить картинку где-то на сайте, но скрывать её через `visibility: hidden` – если скрывать через `display: none`, то элемент выпадет из потока и не загрузится.

Comment: background-position может, а не background: position?

Comment: @RogatnevNikita конечно же, очепятался.

Answer (score 0):

img = new Image ();
img.src="путь к картинке";

Картинка будет в кеше

Comment: я сейчас проверю ваше предложение, но у меня один вопрос: как проверять потом эти изображения в кэше? Спрашиваю я это для того, что бы делать проверку, и при каждой загрузке не загружать в холостую изображение.