# Как подгружать изображения заранее и убрать эффект подгрузки?

Tags: jquery, css, изображения

Есть блок с картинкой, который сменяется при наведении и клике на другие изображения. [Фидл](http://jsfiddle.net/f9p8e2mk/)

Но, есть проблема, что изображения заранее не подгружаются. Как сделать так, чтобы изображения заранее загружались, а не возникал эффект прыгающей подгрузки неприятной глазу?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.div').on('click', function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass("div")) {
      $(this).addClass("div-hover").removeClass("div");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.div {
  background: url("https://bipbap.ru/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/leto_derevo_nebo_peyzazh_dom_derevya_domik_priroda_3000x2000.jpg") no-repeat center center;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
.div:hover {
  background: url("https://bipbap.ru/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/VOLKI-krasivye-i-ochen-umnye-zhivotnye.jpg") no-repeat center center;
  background-size: cover;
}
.div-hover {
  background: url("http://s1.1zoom.me/big0/930/Coast_Sunrises_and_sunsets_Waves_USA_Ocean_Kaneohe_521540_1280x775.jpg") no-repeat center center;
  background-size: cover;
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div"></div>
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как загрузить фото в кеш до запуска сладера?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/759826/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b3%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b7%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%84%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%b5%d1%88-%d0%b4%d0%be-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
body::after{
    position:absolute; width:0; height:0; overflow:hidden; z-index:-1;
    content:url(img01.png) url(img02.png) url(img03.png) url(img04.png);
}
```

и смену картинки по клику я бы реализовал без скрипта

```
.div:focus {
     background: url("http://s1.1zoom.me/big0/930/Coast_Sunrises_and_sunsets_Waves_USA_Ocean_Kaneohe_521540_1280x775.jpg") no-repeat center center;
}
```

Comment: без скрипта - это как? ну вот - прописал фокус стили, дальше что?http://jsfiddle.net/f9p8e2mk/1/

Comment: @Вася, может я и погорячился с :focus у div не все однозначно - если поставить <div tabindex="0" class="div"></div> то работает (только background-size: cover; отменить), но вот на счет как в разных браузерах работать будет зуб не дам. Может есть и другие способы/костыли.